# Is it possibly to privately host a GAE compatible grid?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

I work for a big company - we are not to big on "open" technologies. Our security people are so paranoid that we cannot even login to most web-services (including Google!).

Us devs really like Google technologies, in particular the App engine. Given that we cannot host company services outside the company infrastructure can we do the opposite? I'd like to use some of our department's servers to make a small GAE-compatible grid and use them to run my own application.

We do not need the whole of the GAE experience, for example we do not need Google's APIs - I just want to use the Google BigTable technology for our private projects.

Can this be done?

FYI, We have about 10 servers available for this project (they do not have to all be used). And to complicate matters, most of our machines run Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppScale http://github.com/AppScale/appscale

> AppScale is an open-source hybrid cloud platform. AppScale implements
>   a number of popular APIs including those of Google App Engine,
>   MapReduce (via Hadoop), MPI and others. AppScale executes as a guest
>   virtual machine (guestVM) over any virtualization layer that can host
>   an Ubuntu Lucid image.

Typhoon App Engine http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/

> The TyphoonAE project aims at providing a full-featured and productive
>   serving environment to run Google App Engine (Python) applications. It
>   delivers the parts for building your own scalable App Engine while
>   staying compatible with Google's API.

Answer (score 3):

There is the the open source project [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/)  which mimics the App Engine framework.
It being in development for quite some time and can be hosted on a private cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Check out CapeDwarf (http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf):

> JBoss CapeDwarf is an implementation of the Google App Engine API,
>   which allows applications to be deployed on JBoss Application Servers
>   without modification. Behind the scenes, CapeDwarf uses existing JBoss
>   APIs such as Infinispan, JGroups, PicketLink, HornetQ and others.

Answer (score 0):

There are to popular clones of the Google's BigTable: HBase and Cassandra.  Both implement the same concept but are built completely different internally. Selection between them depends on Your requirements for the consistency and high availability.